# Confusion about definition of $\forall x P(x)$ and about the universal quantifier in general

Tags: logic, quantifiers

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398492/why-is-the-universal-quantifier-forall-x-in-a-px-defined-as-forall-x) I saw the definition (neglecting domain of discourse) 
$$\forall x   P(x) = \forall x ( \;x \in A 
\Longrightarrow P(x) \;).$$

Why isn't the $\forall$ symbol redundant on the RHS? That is, why not just write $$\forall xP(x) = x   ( \;x \in A 
\Longrightarrow P(x) \;)?$$

What is wrong about this? Also, if the latter definition is indeed wrong, then how does one actually define the universal quantifier? I know in categorical logic it's definable as an adjoint, and that definition seems to use implication alone (though I'm not sure).

I'm also confused by [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16095/is-there-formal-definition-of-universal-quantification) where it's written either existential or universal quantification must be taken as a primitive... How does this settle with the categorical definition?

Answer (score 2):

> I saw the definition (neglecting domain of discourse)...

If we neglect $x∈A$ the two formulae are not the same.

The so-called [bounded quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)#Equivalent_expressions)

> $\forall x \ \in A : P(x)$ and $\exists x \ \in A :P(x)$

are *abbreviations* respectively for the two formulae :

> $\forall x (x \in A \to P(x))$ and $\exists x (x \in A \land P(x))$.

The "official syntax" is : $\forall x \varphi$ and $\exists x \varphi$.

In many mathematical context, where the proof is "restricted" to a specific context, like e.g. *natural* numbers, it is very useful to abbreviate the longer : $\forall n (n \in \mathbb N \to P(n))$ with $\forall n \in \mathbb N : P(n)$.